# Data is truncated in a WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

In my Android app, I dynamicly create a `WebView` object's content, and load it into the `WebView` using the command:

```
textView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlText, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

However, it truncates the text. Any idea how I can prevent this from happenning?

The xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.owner.myapplication.MyActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/myapp">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean by truncate? Perhaps it gets off screen or not printed out in its entirety? Can you please provide more info?

Comment: I mean that I see the beginning of the page, but not  the whole page. I have it inside a scrolling activity, and I scroll past the end of the text when the text should still go significantly past the end of the screen.

Comment: So this leads me to believe that your issue is that your parent scrollView is hijacking the scrolling of the child webView (also a view that can scroll) and not that the html content is been truncated. Try hardcoding your webviews height to something like 1000pt and check it out. If you can see the content then this is your issue. Please add your layout xml so I can understand your view hierarchy.

Comment: This is your entire activity layout? It looks like you had left out the CoordinatorLayout part. Do you only need a webview?

Comment: @user3745785 were you able to figure this out?